# How do I create a DHCP server, with a router that doesn't allow me to disable DHCP?

Tags: 14.04, networking

I have an Actiontec V1000H Modem/Router from my ISP Telus, they have blocked access to all their 'advanced' settings like DHCP/Bridging.

I have setup a MAAS server I have a few things I'd like it to manage but the problem I'm having is I can't netboot anything because I cannot use `maas-dhcp` because my router does not allow me to disable it so my netboots cannot find boot media.

So my main question is as the title states,

If I cannot disable DHCP settings on my Modem/Router, how can I make it run in tandem with `maas-dhcp` so that I can netboot images. Thanks.

I've read about setting `next-server` to point to my MAAS machine but I cannot do that with my router.

Comment: I suppose 'I don't want by a second router' is implicit in the question.

Comment: Oh but I would if I could, due to Telus net working I have to use their proprietary modem to get my IP address and what not and they do not support bridging or anything of the sort @muru

Comment: ah you want them to be externally visible, so NAT is not an option.